# Compute Expectation of Product Using Joint Survival Function

Tags: expected-value, joint-distribution, integral

I know that, for a nonnegative random variable $X$,
$$ E[X] = \int x dF(x) = \int S(x) dx$$
where $F(x)$ and $S(x)$ are the CDF and survival function of $X$, respectively.

This was derived using integration by parts, which I only know for one dimension. Is there a corresponding result in the two dimensional case?

> For nonnegative random variables $X$ and $Y$, is
> $$ E[XY] = \int \int xy dH(x,y)$$
> equivalent to something like
> $$ E[XY] = \int \int S(x,y) dxdy .$$
> where $H(x,y)$ and $S(x,y)$ are the joint CDFs and survival functions of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: You might be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/346856/119261.

Comment: Because (assuming $X$ and $Y$ have finite variances) $E[XY] = E[(X+Y)^2/4] - E[(X-Y)^2/4],$ this is really just two univariate integrals.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you have to write $S_{(X+Y)^2/4}$ in terms of $S_{X,Y}$?

Comment: Yes: apply any of your favorite formulas.